# Does ctags support zip or jar file?

Tags: vim, jar, ctags

Does the ctags support zip or jar file?
I want to use ctags in vim to program java.
So I hope ctags search java file in jar.

I do not want to unzip jar, that will hard to manage file.

Answer (score 1):

In the tags database which *ctags* builds, it has to refer to the indexed file, relative to the tags database. Since there is no general notation to refer to contents inside a ZIP file (what may be casually described as `/path/to/archive.zip:dirs/inside/file.txt`), as this is a separate filesystem within the normal filesystem, this is not possible. You have to unzip the JAR files.